# EmberJS, how to monitoring pending AJAX requests

Tags: ajax, ember.js, ember-data

I would like to inform to the User when there is a pending request on going.

The main idea is to display a spinner when there is some pending request, but also would be a nice idea to have the total number of pending requests so I can get to the User a more accurate information.

Is there any place in Ember where I can find this information?, I was checking into the Models but this took me to [a nightmare](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/understanding-ds-model-life-cycle/9590). Also I don't find any thing in the [DS.Store](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html).

Answer (score 0):

Normally Ajax-Requests are wrapped within a Promise.

For Example in a route:

```
this.store.findAll('myModel')
```

This will return a Promise and you can show a spinner while the promise isnt resolved.
Cause this is a often wanted behavior, the route will transition into a loading route and rendering a loading template while the promise of the model hook is still resolving.

https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/routing/loading-and-error-substates/

The Ember Inspector uses logic to inspect Promises.

https://github.com/emberjs/ember-inspector

Maybe you can get some infos how to get alle pending Promises.

Comment: Even if this it looks like a good workaround, as I understand a _promise_ is not actually a pending request. My model tree can be full of promises but I am not waiting for any one to be loaded, and even most of them never will be loaded because I never will need them. Informing the User of the number of pending _promises_ is not really informative for her.